# Is it bad practice to use the system() function when library functions could be used instead? Why?

Tags: language-agnostic, system-calls

Say there is some functionality needed for an application under development which could be achieved by making a system call to either a command line program or utilizing a library. Assuming efficiency is not an issue, is it bad practice to simply make a system call to a program instead of utilizing a library? What are the disadvantages of doing this?

To make things more concrete, an example of this scenario would be an application which needs to download a file from a web server, either the cURL program or the libcURL library could be used for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you are writing code for only one OS, there is no way of knowing if your system call will even work.  What happens when there is a system update or an OS upgrade?
**Never** use a system call if there is a library to do the same function.

Comment: Just this evening I went through a couple of small Perl utility programs of mine and replaced using a system call to the copy command with File::Copy -- new version is shorter and works on all of my platforms instead of just Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer libraries because of the dependency issue, namely the executable might not be there when you call it, but the library will be (assuming external library references get taken care of when the process starts on your platform).  In other words, using libraries would seem to guarantee a more stable, predictable outcome in more environments than system calls would.

Answer (score 3):

There are several factors to take into account.  One key one is the reliability of whether the external program will be present on all systems where your software is installed.  If there is a possibility that it will be missing, then maybe it is better to do it inside your program.

Weighing against that, you might consider that the extra code loaded into your program is prohibitive  - you don't need the code bloat for such a seldom-used part of your application.

The system() function is convenient, but dangerous, not least because it invokes a shell, usually.  You may be better off calling the program more directly - on Unix, via the fork() and exec() system calls.  [Note that a system call is very different from calling the `system()` function, incidentally!]  OTOH, you may need to worry about ensuring all open file descriptors in your program are closed - especially if your program is some sort of daemon running on behalf of other users; that is less of a problem if your are not using special privileges, but it is still a good idea not to give the invoked program access to anything you did not intend.  You may need to look at the `fcntl()` system call and the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag.

Generally, it is easier to keep control of things if you build the functionality into your program, but it is not a trivial decision.

Answer (score 2):

Security is one concern. A malicious cURL could cause havoc in your program. It depends if this is a personal program where coding speed is your main focus, or a commercial application where things like security play a factor.

Answer (score 1):

System calls are much harder to make safely.

All sorts of funny characters need to be correctly encoded to pass arguments in, and the types of encoding may vary by platform or even version of the command. So making a system call that contains any user data at all requires a lot of sanity-checking and it's easy to make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, as mentioned above, keep in mind the difference between system calls (like fcntl() and open()) and system() calls.  :)

In the early stages of prototyping a c program, I often make external calls to programs like grep and sed for manipulation of files using popen().  It's not safe, it's not secure, and it's certainly not portable.  But it can allow you to get going quickly.  That's valuable to me.  It lets me focus on the really important core of the program, usually the reason I used c in the first place.

In high level languages, you'd better have a pretty good reason.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing either, I'd Unix it up and build a script framework around your app, using the command line arguments and stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Other's have mentioned good points (reliability, security, safety, portability, etc) - but I'll throw out another. Performance.  Generally it is many times faster to call a library function or even spawn a new thread then it is to start an entire new process (and then you still have to correctly check/verify it's execution and parse it's output!)