# Stop error output in C++ when making new folder

Tags: c++

I am using C++ on Ubuntu. I have been using the command:

```
 system("mkdir new_folder");
```

to make a new folder called new_folder. However, if that folder already exists, C++ outputs an error message (and continues to run afterwards).

Is there a way to stop the error message from printing out?

Comment: Why not check to see that the folder already exists first, *then* create it if it doesn't exist? Also, blatantly using `system` like that is an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: Why not use [`mkdir`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-Directories.html) and check its return value?

Comment: @jrd1 Please could you explain to me (a beginner) why using system is a bad idea?

Comment: int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode); - no?

Comment: Well, since you're already running a shell command anyway, you can use `"mkdir new_folder > /dev/null 2>&1"`, but that's really not the way to go!

Comment: System becomes dependent on the operating system youre running. Some dont have the same names (windows vs linux) some dont have all the same default binaries (redhat vs ubuntu vs unix)

Comment: Also, [`system()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Running-a-Command) creates a whole new process just to run a simple operation like creating a folder. This is very inefficient and slow. It is also harder to determine what may have caused the corresponding command to fail. Finally, also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509743/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-the-system-function-when-library-functions-could-be) discussion.

Comment: @fushsialatitude: Everyone seems to have added the major aspects. As for other details, read this: http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html. Note, while that applies to `system("pause")`, many of the arguments made apply here too. This is why everyone recommends using the `mkdir` (which is tailored for this purpose), instead. Plus, you also get into race conditions which cause even more problems (example, deleting many files). On the whole avoid relying on `system` to do things, as things can *and do* go awry from time to time.

Comment: Using `system()` is like trying to program without actually programming.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular command use `mkdir -p new_folder`.

Generally, you want to fork your process and on one of the branches redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null or similar then do exec to replace the process with the new one.